# How to query Graph API to get a list of Facebook pages with certain word in the title

Tags: facebook-graph-api

So the title says it all, I want to get a list of public pages on Facebook with certain keywords in their titles. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Search API: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api#search

```
GET graph.facebook.com
  /search?
    q={your-query}&
    type=page
```